# How to show the following grammar is ambiguous?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, context-free-language, ambiguous-grammar

I have the following grammar defined:

```
S -> A|B, A -> aAb | ab, B -> aBb | epsilon;
```

After working for some time, I still couldn't find a string to construct a distinctive parse tree to show that this grammar is ambiguous. Like: aaabbb,abab,etc.  It seemed like this grammar is unambiguous. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This grammar is ambiguous. The string `aabb` can be derived in two different ways:

```
S => A => aAb => aabb
S => B => aBb => aaBbb => aabb
```